# How to realize trajectory similarity query?

Tags: algorithm, similarity, topology

Given a dataset which consists of a large number of trajectories.

And a trajectory is made up of a series of discrete points, GPS location, for example. (2-Dimension)

I need to search all the trajectories that are similar to a given one.

I have found a lot of algorithms, such as edit distance, but I don't know which is the most popular one.

Comment: you should search at math.stackexchange.com (see e.g. [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292345/way-to-measure-the-similarity-difference-of-2d-point-clouds) and [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860503/how-can-i-define-a-measure-of-similarity-between-two-line-segments-in-mathbbr))

Comment: oops, didn't know that, thanks a lot!